# How to remove height and width attributes from CCK ImageField tags?

Tags: 6, entities, media

I am using Drupal 6 with the CCK [ImageField module](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield).  By default, it outputs the height and width of the image as attributes of the tag. For my current project, I'd like to be able to override those with CSS. I have not been able to determine which theme function adds those attributes.

Which functions/templates do I need to override to remove those tags?

Comment: After searching around for a bit I gotta admit I'm stumped! here is some interesting material on the subject but nothing definite: http://drupal.org/node/173880  I guess if you get desperate enough you could just remove the attributes with javascript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for, although it required knowing I was also using ImageCache. I needed to override `theme_imagecache()` in template.php:

```
function mytheme_imagecache($presetname, $path, $alt = '', $title = '', $attributes = NULL, $getsize = TRUE) {
  // Overrode the default here to get ride of height and width attributes.

  // Check is_null() so people can intentionally pass an empty array of
  // to override the defaults completely.
  if (is_null($attributes)) {
    $attributes = array('class' => 'imagecache imagecache-'. $presetname);
  }

  $attributes = drupal_attributes($attributes);
  $imagecache_url = imagecache_create_url($presetname, $path);
  return '<img src="'. $imagecache_url .'" alt="'. check_plain($alt) .'" title="'. check_plain($title) .'" '. $attributes .' />';
}
```

That said, Tim's answer is easier and likely would have worked just as well or better.

Comment: sounds good, if its resolved just make sure to pick an answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

The attributes are there for browser performance reasons. Overriding them with CSS is still possible. If you want to specify the width, set the height to auto, or vice-versa.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that inline attribute tags override CSS but I could be wrong :)

Comment: Try it on any image with firebug, you'll see that it works. Even the stackexchange avatars!

Comment: Inline css, like <img style="width:100px; height:100px;"> would override other CSS, but the height and width attributes are overridden fine.

Comment: sounds about right! :)